# Show that four polynomials are a basis of $\mathbb{R}[x]_{\leq 3}$

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

$V=\mathbb{R}[x]_{\leq 3}$ is the vector space of all polynomials with degree less than or equal to $3$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Show that
$$B = (x^3 − 2x + 3,\ x^3 − 2x^2 + 2x − 1,\ x^3 − 1,\ x^3 − 2x + 5)$$

is a basis of $V$.

My **attempt** at a solution goes as follows:

Since I know the dimensions etc. i can show that B is a basis, by showing the four polynomials are linearly independent.

I tried that by showing that $$\lambda_1 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}3\\-2\\0\\1\end{pmatrix} + \lambda_2 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}-1\\2\\-2\\1\end{pmatrix}+\lambda_3 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}+\lambda_4 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}5\\-2\\0\\1\end{pmatrix} = 0\implies \lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3=\lambda_4=0$$

But this is where im kind of stuck.

If i write it as a matrix I think I can tell that those four columns are indeed not linearly dependent, but I'm unsure of how to show that.

Comment: From the last equality, you can obtain 4 equations (all equating to $0$) in $\lambda_i\in\mathcal R,~1\leq i\leq 4$. Solve that system of equations to show that all the $\lambda_i$ are $0$

Comment: For example, one of the equations is $-2\lambda_2=0$ which automatically gives $\lambda_2=0$ provided $\mathcal R$ has no zero divisors. Two other equations then become $-2(\lambda_1+\lambda_4)=0$ and $\lambda_1+\lambda_3+\lambda_4=0$, using them both gives $\lambda_3=0$. Proceed similarly.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply calculate the determinant. If it is $\neq 0$, then the polynomials are linear independent.